# method of moments estimator and confidence interval - Geometric Distribution

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, geometric-distribution

Question :
[image]

i got to the point(its correct) that :
$\hat{\theta}_{mm}$ = $\frac{1}{\bar{X}}$

$Var(\hat{\theta}_{mm})$ = $\frac{\bar{X}-1}{\bar{X}^3}$

now I need to construct the Confidence Interval for a given $\alpha$.
i get that I need to use Asymptotic Normality but I don't get why in the solutions they divide by $\sqrt{n}$  :
[image]
[image]

Comment: The variance of $\sum X_i$ is $n$ times the variance of $X_i$ so the variance of $\bar X$ is the variance of $X_i$ divided by $n$

Comment: Incidentally, $f(x)=(1-\theta)^{x-1}\theta$ for $x \in \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is not a probability density function.  It would be a probability mass function if it were $(1-\theta)^{x-1}\theta$ for $x \in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ or if it was $(1-\theta)^{x}\theta$ for $x \in \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$